I got blocked to use brush
After selecting object and switching to weight paint mode, not able to apply any brush on specific vertex group in Blender 4.2 LTS update.
Never faced such problem in previous version.

Here in above image no matter how many times brush is moved on weight area it is not affecting it . There were no solutions working shown in similar questions.

How to fix this issue? Where request can be sent regarding this to remove block?

pls i really need help its been a day , still facing issue .
